# Dynamic pivot MySQL

Tags: mysql

Let's say I have a table that looks like:

```
ID   |   Item       |   Purchased  
17   |   Chocolate  |       1304       
17   |    Biscuit   |     1209           
17   |     Jelly    |     657            
17   |     Milk     |      2234
```

I want it to convert such data dynamically into (columns increase dynamically):

```
ID | Chocolate_Purchased | Biscuit_Purchased | Jelly_Purchased | Milk_Purchased
17   | 1304              | 1209              |  657            |  2234
```

How can I achieve this in MySQL?? I need to work on very large amounts of records so can somebody please give me the methods that would be efficient??

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: Good question!! Because it's needed that way.

Comment: It would be better to do this in the application which requests that data.

Comment: That sounds like a problem for presentation in the application layer.

Comment: Hmm.. Is there any way to achieve this in Excel?? Like in Pivot Table or something??

Comment: How can this be achieved in Excel through Pivot Tables???

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT id,SUM(CASE WHEN Item='Chocolate' THEN Purchased END) as Chocolate_Purchased,
SUM(CASE WHEN Item='Biscuit' THEN Purchased END) as Biscuit_Purchased,
SUM(CASE WHEN Item='Jelly' THEN Purchased END) Jelly_Purchased,
SUM(CASE WHEN Item='Mile' THEN Purchased END) as Mile_Purchased 
GROUP BY id
```

Here is the dynamic version

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'SUM(IF(t.item = ''',
      item,
      ''', t.purchased, 0)) AS ',
      item
    )
   )INTO @sql
FROM t;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT id,
                     ', @sql, ' 
                   FROM t               
                   GROUP BY id');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/adffd/1)

Comment: How can this be achieved at runtime?? I mean, can those columns be created dynamically, say, if there are 1000 Rows for ID 17, then how do I create 1000 columns without having to manually write CASE statement 1000 times???

Comment: @KrishnaKanth Give it a try.

Comment: Why is SUM used here? What is it doing in this code??

Comment: @KrishnaKanth It`s pretyy self-explanatory,it add up all purchased values for each item.

Comment: Thank you so much.. Just tried it out in Fiddle.. Cleared it. Thanks!!