# Selecting Some Rows and Showing Diffently

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table like this:

```
ID Student_ID Name      Surname    Grade     Address
----------------------------------------------------
1   111       John      Doe          A     address1
2   112       Michael  Jackson       B     address2
3   155       John      Petrucci     A     address3
...
...
```

What I want to do is, take this output somehow:

```
John Doe Michael Jackson John Petrucci ...
A           B               A          ...
```

But I have 495 students. One row for ID, 3 rows for created_at, updated_at and deleted_at makes 495 + 1 + 3 = 499 columns.

I can't make a table like this, I guess. What must I do? Take all rows (I got more than 5 Million lines of data) and put them in a table in PHP?

I just want to show data in a different way. I don't want to store them, edit them. I just want to show them differently. How can I achieve this?

Thank you very much.

**EDIT:**

I have this table:

```
+---------+----------+-------+----------+-------+-------+---------------------+
| id      | query_id | name  | time     | value | pct   | query_time          |
+---------+----------+-------+----------+-------+-------+---------------------+
| 5051657 |     9983 | AAA   | 14:31:28 | 1,12  | 0,00  | 2014-09-19 14:59:32 |
| 5051656 |     9983 | BBB   | 14:35:03 | 6,77  | 0,30  | 2014-09-19 14:59:32 |
| 5051655 |     9983 | CCC   | 14:33:58 | 5,04  | -0,59 | 2014-09-19 14:59:32 |
| 5051654 |     9983 | DDD   | 14:32:30 | 0,55  | 0,00  | 2014-09-19 14:59:32 |
| 5051653 |     9983 | EEE   | 14:25:59 | 2,01  | 0,00  | 2014-09-19 14:59:32 |
| 5051652 |     9983 | FFF   | 14:30:05 | 2,00  | 0,00  | 2014-09-19 14:59:32 |
| 5051651 |     9983 | GGG   | 14:35:00 | 12,20 | 0,41  | 2014-09-19 14:59:32 |
| 5051650 |     9983 | HHH   | 14:26:26 | 4,06  | 1,00  | 2014-09-19 14:59:32 |
| 5051649 |     9983 | III   | 14:35:06 | 18,80 | 2,17  | 2014-09-19 14:59:32 |
| 5051648 |     9983 | JJJ   | 14:34:04 | 3,11  | 1,63  | 2014-09-19 14:59:32 |
+---------+----------+-------+----------+-------+-------+---------------------+
```

What I want is something like this:

```
+----------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| query_id | AAA | BBB | CCC | DDD | EEE | FFF | GGG | HHH | III | JJJ |
+----------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| 1        | 1,12| 6,77|-0,59|0,00 |0,00 |0,00 | 0,41|1,00 |2,17 | 1,63|
| 2        | 1,13| 6,33|-0,33|0,33 |0,11 |0,45 | 0,56|1,34 |2,45 | 1,19|
+----------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

I just want a CSV file if possible. I got more than 5 million lines and it's growing. I think I have to do this -maybe- everyday. What are my options, how can I do this?

Thank you very much.

Comment: It looks like you want to pivot the rows into columns via a SQL query? Is that right?

Comment: Could you use JSFiddle to provide an example of what you have vs what you want? The expectations here are a bit unclear to me.

Comment: Your proposed output doesn't include any of the other columns (id, created_at, deleted_at)  Are you really only looking for the name/grade displayed horizontally?

Comment: ...If so, you may SELECT only those two columns and return them as normal associative results. Then loop twice over your output - the first time to list names in a row, the second time to list grades beneath them.

Comment: How many different values you have in name?

Comment: @Mihai I have 495 distinct names.

Comment: It wouldn't make sense to have a table with 495 columns. It would be hard to read.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I guess we can forget about those 3. I don't just want them horizontally. I want some values to be printed and some don't. I want some in rows and some in columns. Something stupid, I know. But I can't describe the stupidness of this to people. They want columns, I tell them it's stupid. They don't understand.

Comment: You can use a pivot ! 
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Here is an example of dynamic pivot I did,but a table with 100s of columns is whack http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25409022/dynamic-pivot-mysql/25409090#25409090

Comment: @JohnGuan This won't be read. It will be inputted to an analyzation(?) tool of some kind.

Answer (score 0):

Alright I believe this what you need. With a little bit of research, here's the SQL Fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/56f62/23

```
SET @query = NULL;
SELECT
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
        CONCAT('MAX(IF(name = ''', name, ''', value, 0)) AS ', name)
    )INTO @query
FROM tbl_name;

SET @query = CONCAT('SELECT ', @query, ' FROM tbl_name');

PREPARE statement FROM @query;
EXECUTE statement;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE statement;
```

Comment: It works perfect at SQL Fiddle, but fails in my local environment. I checked my MySQL version and it differs from SQL Fiddle's version. I get this error. Can you help me? Thank you very much. My table name is table_name. That's not the problem. `mysql> PREPARE statement FROM @query;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM table_name' at line 1`

Comment: What MySQL version are you using?

Comment: Here's the output of `mysql --version` command: `mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.37, for debian-linux-gnu (i686) using readline 6.2` Thank you very much.