# Can I return column header names as values in a dynamic pivot table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, pivot-table

First time poster, so apologies for any issues with this.

I have created a dynamic pivot table in MS SQL Server Management Studio that shows whether an employee has a certain skill set. The column headers represent the skills I wish to search on, and can be one or many. Currently it looks something like this;

```
StaffMember | Skill1 | Skill2 | Skill3 | Skill4
```

Where the staff member has the skill, the table returns a `1`, and where they do not, it returns a `0`. I want to be able to concatenate all the fields into one string, using the column headers as the value, and adding some basic formatting, ie;

```
Joe Bloggs [Skill1-Skill4]
```

This will then be returned to my MS Excel front-end application.

Can anyone assist?

UPDATE:

```
DECLARE @SQLQuery NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @SQLQuery = '

SELECT *
FROM
(
SELECT EmployeeID, SkillID AS SkillData
FROM Skills
) P

PIVOT ( 
COUNT(SkillData)
FOR [SkillData] IN (' + @KeySkills + ')
) AS Piv
'
```

This is what I am executing (via sp_executeSQL @SQLQuery), where the variable @KeySkills could be any number of skills. The output displays a `1` if the user has the relevant skill.

It needs to be dynamic as I cannot control how many skills are queried, via @KeySkills.

I want to be able to be able to concatenate the column names, where the value is `1`. This I can return to the front-end application to act as a visual marker that the staff member has these skills.

Comment: Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25409022/dynamic-pivot-mysql

Comment: Assuming that your skills don't have numbers in their names, it's hard for us to imagine the logic you want to implement here.   If you can write out a set of logic rules to be followed, the query will probably write itself.

Comment: @OP: Post your query that generated pivot. It helps to modify and get desired solution

Comment: Thanks @RavinderReddy, i have done that now.

Answer (score 0):

Creating the pivot list dynamically can be done using a FOR XML to build the column string + STUFF to drop the leading comma:

```
DECLARE @KeySkills NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @KeySkills=STUFF(
    (SELECT DISTINCT
        ','+QUOTENAME(SkillID)
    FROM
        Skills
    FOR XML PATH('')),
    1,
    1,
    ''
);
```